# how to remove the duplicate fields from SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a SQL query with a similar kind of record like below as well  as the expected outcome. Basically, to fetch the Project records with the top most FundSrc in the list.
Can someone please suggest a query for this?

e.g- Tablename- Proj

```
| Project | FundSrc |
|---------|---------|
| 1001    | ABC     |
| 1001    | XYZ     |
| 1001    | TYS     |
| 1002    | XYZ     |
| 1002    | TYS     |
| 1003    | ABC     |
| 1003    | TYS     |
| 1003    | TYS     |
```

Expected outcome-

Result

```
| Project   | FundSrc   |
|---------  |---------  |
| 1001      | ABC       |
| 1002      | XYZ       |
| 1003      | ABC       |
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) "topmost" means nothing unless a column defines the ordering.

Comment: what is the logic to get the "top" fundsrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find duplicate rows using the `GROUP BY` clause or `ROW_NUMBER()` function.
Use the `DELETE` statement to remove duplicate rows.

```
SELECT [Project], 
      [FundSrc], 
      COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[dbname]
GROUP BY [Project], 
      [FundSrc]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

First, the CTE uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to find the duplicate rows specified by values in the `Projectand` and `FundSrc` columns.
Then, the `DELETE` statement deletes all the duplicate rows but keeps only one occurrence of each duplicate group.

Comment: Thank you, I think this should resolve the issue I have. I cant actually amend anything in the database, but need an interim solution. So your suggestion should help

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets. There is not "topmost" value *unless a column specifies what "topmost" means*. Your data doesn't have such a column.

If it did, then you would have different options. One simple way uses `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by project order by <ordering col> desc) as seqnum
      from proj p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ordering column to avoid random result

```
with source (key, value, o) as (values
    (1001, 'ABC', 1),
    (1001, 'XYZ', 2),
    (1001, 'TYS', 3),
    (1002, 'XYZ', 4),
    (1002, 'TYS', 5),
    (1003, 'ABC', 6),
    (1003, 'TYS', 7),
    (1003, 'TYS', 8)
)
select distinct key, first_value (value) over (partition by key order by o) from source
;
```